# HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request using base64 encoding in java

Tags: java, http-post

I am using http request. I have two image to call api. Image are base64encoding..but in postman it is working fine. It is not working in my java code..it shows bellow error

```
response = HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request [Server: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu), Date: Fri, 13 Nov 2020 09:24:20 GMT, Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8, Content-Length: 3866, Connection: keep-alive, X-Powered-By: Express, Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *, Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, x-auth-token, x-login-token, x-verification-token, ETag: W/"f1a-xqn4nWVQUqRNj8g2mv5av6fbTrg"]
statusCode = 400
```

1. Postman header image
   [image]
2. Postman body
   [image]

1. I have used bellow code..

   ```
   byte[] photo1=null;
    byte[] photo2=null;
     String base64encodedString = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(photo1);
    String base64encodedString2 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(photo2);
     try {
       DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());           
       HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("url");
       JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
       try {
           jsonObject.put("photo", base64encodedString);
           jsonObject.put("nidFront", base64encodedString2);

       } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }

       System.out.println("jsonObject = " + jsonObject);
       StringEntity params = new StringEntity(String.valueOf(jsonObject));
        httppost.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
       httppost.setHeader("x-auth-token", token);
       httppost.setEntity(params);
       HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);          
       int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
       System.out.println("statusCode = " + statusCode);
   ```

Please help me what is wrong in code

Comment: Please show the JSON you send via postman in your question.

Comment: @tgdavies  when i print jsonobject it shows only one key value

Comment: @tgdavies {"nidFront":"/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAgGBgcGBQgHBwcJ..."}

Comment: use addHeader for both content-type and token.  Print your request here so we can see what you are actually sending, in order to help you further

Comment: Enable logging so you can debug it

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9482717/turning-on-logging-in-httpclient